# Prove that $\frac{1}{1-x}\geq e^x$ for all $x<0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I need to prove that $\frac{1}{1-x}\geq e^x$ for all $x<1$. I've allready proved that $1+x\leq e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I've had some other ideas but I'm not allowed to use anything to different from basic analysis of functions and series, i.e. no differentials or integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=-x$

$$\frac{1}{1-x}\geq e^x \iff \frac{1}{1+y}\geq e^{-y}\iff e^y \geq 1+y$$

Comment: Thanks. I think I was to deep inside to see this.

Comment: When you have negative variable the first thing to do is alway convert in positive!

Answer (score 2):

You have $1+x\leq e^x$ so $\dfrac{1}{1+x}\geq e^{-x}$, let $y=-x<0$ then 
$$e^y\leq\dfrac{1}{1-y}$$

Comment: @gimusi Thanks. Actually I didn't know what to prove!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye.